# Не выводит шаблон django

Tags: html, python, django, backend

Добрый день! Версия Django = 1.11
После ввода неправильного пароля перекидывает на пустую страницу без какого-либо текста.
В задумке, чтобы после ввода неправильного пароля пользователь переходил на disable_account
view

```
def disable_account(request):
     return render(request, 'registration/disable_account.html', {})

def user_view(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/user_view.html', {})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
url(r'^login/$', views.log, name='log'),
url(r'^disable_account/$', views.disable_account, name='disable_account'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logged, name='logged'),
```

base.html

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="/">Django Test</a></h1>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}

<div align = "right">
    <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Привет! {{ request.user.first_name }}, <a href="{% url "logged" %}">Выход</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "log" %}">Вход</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
        </div>
        {%block log%}{%endblock%}
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

disable_account.html

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Аккаунт не найдет{% endblock %}
{% block disable %}
    <h1>Аккаунт не найдет</h1>
    <p>Возможно вы не зарегестрированны или вы даун. 
    Вы можете попробывать <a href="{% url "log" %}">войти</a> снова.</p>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: А что в форме входа? Перед disable_account никаких декораторов не стоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте редирект из view функции
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect